# UFW blocks pihole traffic after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: dns, ufw

I'm a bit lost here. After upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 via `do-release-upgrade`, my pihole stopped working. All queries towards the server over LAN time out, both `pihole.log` and `FTL.log` show no activity. Reinstalling ufw had no effect.

Accessing things locally on the server, via curl, works. Disabling UFW works. UFW, when enabled, seems to be correctly processing rules, as I can still ssh into the server.

**UFW version**

```
~/pihole$ sudo ufw version
ufw 0.36.1
Copyright 2008-2021 Canonical Ltd.
```

**UFW rules**

```
~/pihole$ sudo ufw show added
Added user rules (see 'ufw status' for running firewall):
ufw allow 22/tcp
ufw allow plexmediaserver-all
ufw allow Samba
ufw allow unifi-limited
ufw allow 8123/tcp comment 'HASSIO'
ufw allow 1883 comment 'MQTT'
ufw allow 8096/tcp comment 'JellyFin'
ufw allow 8384 comment 'Syncthing'
ufw allow syncthing
ufw allow 80/tcp comment 'pihole'
ufw allow 53/tcp comment 'pihole'
ufw allow 53/udp comment 'pihole'
```

**Docker compose**

```
cat ~/pihole/docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

networks:
  pihole:
    driver: bridge
services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
    networks:
      - pihole
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/London'
      WEBPASSWORD: '<redacted>'
      PIHOLE_DNS_: '1.1.1.1;1.0.0.1'
    volumes:
      - './etc-pihole:/etc/pihole'
      - './etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d'
      - './log/:/var/log/pihole'
    restart: unless-stopped
```